# SQL bindParam not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, bindparam

I have problem with my code, I can't show data from my database I am using bindParam() and bindValue() it's still not working.

This is my code:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
try{
    $database = new Connection();
    $db = $database->openConnection();

    $sql = "SELECT users.username, users.user_id, topic.*, post.* 
            FROM users INNER JOIN post
            ON users.user_id = post.user_id
            INNER JOIN topic
            ON topic.topic_id = post.topic_id
            WHERE topic.topic_id = :id";

    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->bindValue(":id", $id);
    $stm->execute();
    $row = $stm->fetch();

    foreach($db->query($sql) as $row){
        echo "<td>". $row['content'] . "</td>";
    }

}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'Connection Problem: '. $e->getMessage();
}
```

i am get this error:

```
 Connection Problem: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':id' at line 6
```

but when i am use

```
$sql = "SELECT users.username, users.user_id, topic.*, post.* 
            FROM users INNER JOIN post
            ON users.user_id = post.user_id
            INNER JOIN topic
            ON topic.topic_id = post.topic_id
            WHERE topic.topic_id = ". $id;

$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute();
```

It worked perfectly

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$db->query($sql)` You're running the query again instead of fetching the results.

Comment: Does you $id variable contain ':id'? example: http://thisinterestsme.com/pdo-updating-mysql-prepared-statements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `bindValue()` code, your loop is wrong. You should be looping over the array `$row` It should be

```
foreach($row as $value){
   echo "<td>". $value['content'] . "</td>";
}
```